# Django Rest Framework - Serialize nested objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this JSON input which I'd like to express properly in the Django Model in order to be correctly serialized by Django Rest Framework.

- the MainObject has *name* property and a *list of conditions*;
- each Condition is composed exactly by 2 blocks: *left* and *right*;
- each Block is composed by 1 field *title* and a *list of user_params*.

```
    {
        "name": "The Main Object Name",
        "conditions": [
            {
                "left": {
                    "title": "Title1",
                    "user_params": [
                        {
                            "name": "name_param_X",
                            "value": "100"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "right": {
                    "title": "Title2",
                    "user_params": [
                        {
                            "name": "name_param_Y",
                            "value": "200"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

And here my models:

```
class MainObject(models.Model):
    main_object_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Condition(models.Model):
    condition_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    main_object = models.ForeignKey(MainObject, related_name="conditions",
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    left = models.OneToOneField(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='left')
    right = models.OneToOneField(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='right')

class Block(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)

class BlockParam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    block_title = models.ForeignKey(Block, related_name="user_params",
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializers:

```
class ConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    condition_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Condition
        fields = ('condition_id', 'left', 'right')

class MainObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conditions = ConditionSerializer(many=True)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        conditions_data = validated_data.pop("conditions")
        main_object = MainObject.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for condition_data in conditions_data:
            Condition.objects.create(main_object=main_object, **condition_data)
        return main_object
```

The **issue**: when I do a POST request to create a MainObject with the aforementioned JSON input, I receive 400 Bad response with this message:

```
{
    "conditions": [
        {
            "left": [
                "Invalid pk \"{'title': 'Title1', 'user_params': [{'name': 'name_param_x', 'value': '100'}]}\" - object does not exist."
            ],
            "right": [
                "Invalid pk \"{'title': 'Title2', 'user_params': [{'name': 'name_param_y', 'value': '200'}]}\" - object does not exist."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My questions:

1. Are the models correctly modelled according to the desired JSON input structure?
2. Do I need to modify the serializers in order to get it work?